# Duplicate field values in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite 3.11. I create a table as follows:

```
            CREATE TABLE MyTable (F1 INTEGER, F2 INTEGER, F3 INTEGER);
```

Then add the following records:

```
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (1, 2, 8); 
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (1, 3, 9);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (2, 4, 8);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (2, 5, 2);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (3, 6, 4);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (3, 7, 8);
            INSERT INTO MyTable (F1, F2, F3) Values (4, 2, 4);
```

Now if two records have the same value of F1, then I will define them as conflict records.

I want to select all the records whose (F3 & 8) != 0 where (F3 & 8) means to get the third bit of the F3 value. Moreover, for conflict records, I will order them by F2 and only the record with the largest F2 will be selected.

So for the above sample, the following record will be selected:

```
            (1, 3, 9)
            (2, 4, 8)
            (3, 7, 8)
```

How to do that?

I first try the following command:

```
            SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ((F3 & 8) != 0) ORDER BY F2 DESC;
```

But that will return:

```
            (3, 7, 8)
            (2, 4, 8)
            (1, 3, 9)
            (1, 2 8)
```

If I use the following command:

```
            SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ((F3 & 8) != 0) ORDER BY F2 DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then it will return:

```
            (3, 7, 8)
```

Both are incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you've already tried. And `4` does not have the third bit set.

Comment: @CL, SOrry for the mistake. I have just corrected it. Also I find out the way to mark the answers. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CL, I have updated the question by adding what I have tried. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get one output row per group, use GROUP BY.
In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can select which row in a group to output with MIN()/MAX() (in older SQLite versions or standard SQL, the MAX() would not affect other columns such as `F3`):

```
SELECT F1,
       MAX(F2) AS F2,
       F3
FROM MyTable
WHERE (F3 & 8) != 0
GROUP BY F1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, though it is a bit strange that the function of MAX(F2) will affect other columns.